# Polymer elements and mouse click event

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to simulate a click on a polymer element. To be more specific, I'm using paper-dropdown-menu as an example (https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown-menu/demo.html). I want to programatically select an item by triggering events. Whenever I invoke a click on the element it doesn't have any effect.

I'm trying to invoke mouse click like: 

`document.querySelector('paper-dropdown-menu').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

With CustomEvent I could dispatch and listen it :

To dispacth:

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("successEvent", {'detail': response}));
```

to listen :

```
document.addEventListener('successEvent', function(event) {
                    this.result = JSON.stringify(event.detail);}.bind(this));
```

Are you listening MouseEvent ?

You can use [Polymer-gesture](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/touch.html) to manage MouseEvent and TouchEvent.

Comment: Deprecated now! It was available for the 0.5 or 1.0 Polymer version